# PHP replace value after specific string

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace, strpos

I have this string: `$path = "[other values] and dateStart >= '2021-01-01' and dateEnd <= '2021-12-31' and [other values ...]'";`

What I am tring to do is to replace the value after `dateStart`  with `2021-02-02`.

I tried using `$test = substr($path, 0, strpos($path, 'dateStart >= '));` but it only returns everything before 'dateStart' ...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you change `dateStart` with `2021-02-02`, will it make sense, because the end date will be smaller?

Comment: `substr` *Returns the portion of string specified by the offset and length parameters.* and  `strpos` will *Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.* There is no notion of `2021-02-02` as a replacement in the code.

Comment: @nice_dev, no as I need to change multiple values (like dateStart & dateEnd) but as soon as I have one working method I can apply it to all the values I need to change; I just try too keep it simple for you guys ;)

Comment: @ddl Fair enough, regular expressions is a good start for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to want to replace the dateStart, you could use a pattern to match a date like pattern and replace the match with your new string.

Then you could update the pattern to also do the replacement for dateEnd.

```
\bdateStart\h+>=\h+'\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=')
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dAaVao/1)

```
$re = '/\bdateStart\h+>=\h+\'\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=\')/m';
$path = "[other values] and dateStart >= '2021-01-01' and dateEnd <= '2021-12-31' and [other values ...]'";
echo preg_replace($re, '2021-02-02', $path);
```

Output

```
[other values] and dateStart >= '2021-02-02' and dateEnd <= '2021-12-31' and [other values ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '2021-01-01';
$replace = "2021-02-02";
$path = "[other values] and dateStart >= '2021-01-01' and dateEnd <= '2021-12-31' and [other values ...]'";
$pos = strpos($path, $date);
$test = substr($path, 0, $pos);
$test = $test.$replace.substr($path, $pos + strlen($date));
```